# SSAS 2008 proactive caching not working on views?

Tags: ssas

I created some views as dimensions and fact. I set up proactive caching on measures hoping to see the update on measures automatically. In storage settings, I set up Automatically MOLAP for the partition (just one partition for the measure group) and in the Options, set Silence interval and Silence override interval to 10 seconds and 10 minutes respectively. Also checked Bring online immediately and Enable ROLAP aggregations. In the notification tab, I specified tracking table (SQL Server) as the fact view.

I deployed project. But when I manually add or delete a row in the underlying table of the fact view, there is no update in the cube browser after refreshing.

To prove this, I create another project with all the same dimensions and facts, except instead using views I used actual tables. With all the same proactive caching, this time I am able to see the changes (add/delete rows from fact table) after refreshing in the cube browser.

So anyone can explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure SSAS to track the underlying tables instead of the view.